# config Mailhandler.php in contact form

Tags: php, email

I have an error downloading a template from TemplateMonster but I'm setting section, contact form for sending email but I get a message that was sent , but if I do not get anything here ami mail muestor code.

MailHandler.php

```
<?php
$owner_email='darksihart19@gmail.com';
//SMTP server settings  
$host = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
$port = '465';//"587";
$username = 'test@gmail.com';
$password = 'test';

$subject='A message from your site visitor ';
$user_email='';    
$message_body='';
$message_type='html';

$max_file_size=50;//MB 
$file_types='/(doc|docx|txt|pdf|zip|rar)$/';
$error_text='something goes wrong';
$error_text_filesize='File size must be less than';
$error_text_filetype='Failed to upload file. This file type is not allowed. Accepted files types: doc, docx, txt, pdf, zip, rar.';

$private_recaptcha_key='6LeZwukSAAAAACmqrbLmdpvdhC68NLB1c9EA5vzU'; //localhost


$use_recaptcha=isset( $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"]) and isset($_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);
$use_smtp=($host=='' or $username=='' or $password=='');
$max_file_size*=1048576;

if($owner_email=='' || $owner_email=='#' ){
    die('Attention, recipient e-mail is not set! Please define "owner_email" variable in the MailHanlder.php file.');
}

if(preg_match('/^(127\.|192\.168\.)/',$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])){
    die('Attention, contact form will not work locally! Please upload your template to a live hosting server.');
}

if($use_recaptcha){
    require_once('recaptchalib.php');
    $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($private_recaptcha_key,$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],$_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],$_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);
    if (!$resp->is_valid){
        die ('wrong captcha');
    }
}

if(isset($_POST['name']) and $_POST['name'] != ''){$message_body .= '<p>Visitor: ' . $_POST['name'] . '</p>' . "\n" . '<br>' . "\n"; $subject.=$_POST['name'];}
if(isset($_POST['email']) and $_POST['email'] != ''){$message_body .= '<p>Email Address: ' . $_POST['email'] . '</p>' . "\n" . '<br>' . "\n"; $user_email=$_POST['email'];}
if(isset($_POST['state']) and $_POST['state'] != ''){$message_body .= '<p>State: ' . $_POST['state'] . '</p>' . "\n" . '<br>' . "\n";}
if(isset($_POST['phone']) and $_POST['phone'] != ''){$message_body .= '<p>Phone Number: ' . $_POST['phone'] . '</p>' . "\n" . '<br>' . "\n";}   
if(isset($_POST['fax']) and $_POST['fax'] != ''){$message_body .= '<p>Fax Number: ' . $_POST['fax'] . '</p>' . "\n" . '<br>' . "\n";}
if(isset($_POST['message']) and $_POST['message'] != ''){$message_body .= '<p>Message: ' . $_POST['message'] . '</p>' . "\n";}  
if(isset($_POST['stripHTML']) and $_POST['stripHTML']=='true'){$message_body = strip_tags($message_body);$message_type='text';}try{
include "libmail.php";
$m= new Mail("utf-8");
$m->From($user_email);
$m->To($owner_email);
$m->Subject($subject);
$m->Body($message_body,$message_type);
//$m->log_on(true);

if(isset($_FILES['attachment'])){
    if($_FILES['attachment']['size']>$max_file_size){
        $error_text=$error_text_filesize . ' ' . $max_file_size . 'bytes';
        die($error_text);           
    }else{          
        if(preg_match($file_types,$_FILES['attachment']['name'])){
            $m->Attach($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'],$_FILES['attachment']['name'],'','attachment');
        }else{
            $error_text=$error_text_filetype;
            die($error_text);               
        }
    }       
}
if(!$use_smtp){
    $m->smtp_on( $host, $username, $password, $port);
}

if($m->Send()){
    die('success');
}   }catch(Exception $mail){
die($mail);}?>
```

if I just put out the address sending the message but does not show my e- mail if I set everything with username and password SMTP server I get an error message ! but it shows no content something is wrong with my code or am setting bad

Comment: Enable the debug flags, if it has any. (This is just the settings file. Nobody can help with that unless you also reveal the connection code and the library it's based on. "Some template" is too vague.)

Answer (score 0):

Try using  [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)  instead. In this library you can set `SMTPDebug` parameter which helps you to handle mailing errors. Example is in Github repo. Or enable Zend Debugger in your IDE to see what's going wrong.